# Apache Tomcat - Webservice in PERL

Tags: perl, apache, tomcat7

Good morning.

Is it possible to publish a web service made ​​in PERL in Apache Tomcat?
If yes, where can I see an example?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is [no such thing as PERL](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Tomcat is a Java Servlet container, it is not well suited to running anything else.

That said, you can use [CGI](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/cgi-howto.html) (with all its drawbacks) with Tomcat and *everything* supports CGI. Writing raw CGI in Perl is trivial, but there are [modules](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI) to help and [Plack supports CGI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Plack/lib/Plack/Handler/CGI.pm).

However, if you wan to use Perl, then you would be much better off with a general purpose webserver and not something designed specifically for Java.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

What would you consider the best way to configure a Web server to use WebServices developed in PERL?

Thank you.

Comment: [Plack](http://plackperl.org/) via Starman, Nginx or Apache HTTPD (or some other HTTP server that Plack supports via something efficient (not CGI, but FastCGI is good) that you are using already).